# How to rewrite / proxy an Apache URI to an application listening on a specific port / server?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, port, mod-proxy

They say that Apache's mod_rewrite is the swiss-army knife of URL manipulation, but can it do this?

Lets say I want to add a new application to my Apache webserver, where the only configurable option of the app is a port number.

I want to use & give out URLs of the form "http://hostname.example.com/app" rather than "http://hostname.example.com:8080". This would ensure that clients would be getting through the institution's firewall as well, and it's generally tidier.

My application includes absolute URIs in php, javascript and css, so I want to prepend my own root location to the URI in the applications internal links. I have no access to DNS records and so can't create another name-based virtual server.

Using Apache's mod_rewrite and mod_proxy modules, I can transparently redirect a client to the correct home-page of the application. But links within that homepage don't point a client to links relative to the new base URL.

So, what's the best way of proxying a request to an application that is listening on a specific port?

For example, if I had an application listening on port 8080, I could put this in my Apache configuration:-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SSLProxyEngine On
    ServerName myhost.example.com
    RewriteEngine On
    UseCanonicalName On
    ProxyVia On
    <Location "/application">
        RewriteRule ^/application/?(.*) http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This would work fine if the application didn't use absolute URLs, but it does. What I need to do is rewrite URLs that are returned by the application's css, javascript and php.

I've looked at the ProxyPass and ReverseProxyPass documentation, but I don't think these would work..?

I've also come across Nick Kew's [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/), but this isn't included in the standard Apache Distribution, and my institution's webserver seems to have been fine for years without it.. Other than trawling manually (or using a grep -r | sed type expression) through the application's source code, or using this 3rd party add-on, are there any other ways to go about this?

Could I perhaps use some of the internal server variables in a mod_rewrite rule? For example a rewrite rule based on ’HTTP_REFERER'?

Comment: You need mod-proxy-html, because internal links in webpages might point outside `application/`, if they begin with `/` (they are not fixable by proxy, because e.g. `/img/abc` request is ambiguous without context: `application/img/abc` or really `/img/abc`). Cannot you fix the app to use only relative links?

Comment: Thought I replied to this... :S
The apps in question are not directory based (daemon applications that listen on their own port) and don't refer to anything outside of their respective root directories.
I did try fixing all of the absolute URIs in one app (pathway tools), but this just killed the app. This was also a lot of work, and would need to be repeated should an update replace anything important (some of which could be distributed as binary and thus would be uneditable; no doubt why this app broke).
Ta tho :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using mod_proxy would work just fine. For instance, I mapped `https://localhost/yalla/` to point to a subdirectory of my webserver:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
ProxyRequests On
<Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /yalla/ http://yalla.ynfonatic.de/tmp/
```

If you implement this, you'll note that the pictues of the directory-listing aren't visible; this is because they're *below* the /tmp/ directory on the remote server, hence not visible.

So, in your case you'd do:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
ProxyRequests On
<Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from localhost # Or whatever your network is if you need an ACL
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /app/ http://hostname.example.com:8080/
```

Like with everything in Apache configuration, watch those trailing slashes when referring to directories.

Good luck!
Alex.

Comment: Looks like this could work. Ta!
Was looking at mod_proxy this morning actually, to see about auto-proxying my home network through the uni's one.. That's completely different functionality from this though.
Will let you know how I get on. Cheers! Alex

Comment: This seems to drop preflight options requests

Comment: @nathan For that you might need some `mod_rewrite` sauce; I never stumbled upon that error, but a quick search revealed this link: https://songbard.wordpress.com/2011/05/27/coaxing-apache-to-honour-options/ - not sure, if that helps, but feedback is welcome. YMMV.

Comment: `ProxyRequests on` seems a dangerous mistake: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests