# Apache httpd mod_proxy_balancer: broadcast to all cluster members?

Tags: apache, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I have a few HTTP/PHP servers fronted by an Apache/mod_proxy_balancer load balancer, with a typical cluster setup as below:

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.10
    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.11
    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.12
    BalancerMember http://192.168.1.13
</Proxy>
```

My question: is there a way to configure Apache such that some specific requests can be sent to all members of the cluster instead of being the standard proxied to one?

I ask because each member in my cluster uses a local data cache based on XCache. Each member has a http-accessible script to unset specific cache item on itself. On some rare events, I need to clear the same cache entry on all servers.

I could make a separate bash/curl script to hit each server in sequence, but since the cluster definition is in my `httpd.conf`, it'd be easier to not have to copy it somewhere else, and also, I'm hoping to retain a curl-able endpoint on the load balancer itself to do a global cache clearing.

Note: I am **not** asking about memcache. I'm already using memcache for other things, where servers need to have synchronized storage. In this case I use Xcache for almost-persistent, no-sync-required, data caching.

Comment: i think you will need to send this to the members manually, there does not seem to be a documented way to do this with Apache itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rewrite / proxy an Apache URI to an application listening on a specific port / server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529324/how-to-rewrite-proxy-an-apache-uri-to-an-application-listening-on-a-specific-p)