# how set website and webservice on the same port (8080)?

Tags: apache, tomcat, port

In a server hosting a website address.com (managed with drupal) with an apache2 server (running on port 8080) I would like to install a webservice (tomcat7 / axis2) which runs on the same port 8080. Is there a way do it? There're also svn, trac running on that port. Unfortunately, due to security restrictions, that's the only port accessible externally.
Thank you

Comment: You can't run two processes (ie: Tomcat 7 + SVN) on the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely expose multiple services on the same port, as long as they all live in distinct URL namespaces.  For example, you're already running Trac and svn on port 8080, so obviously you are *already* doing exactly what you're asking about.

To add Tomcat to the mix, you would typically:

- Run Tomcat locally on another port, and then
- Use `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` to expose the Tomcat service via your webserver on port 8080.

For example, if you wanted to make your Tomcat instance visible at `http://myserver:8080/tomcat`, you might add something like this to your Apache configuration:

```
ProxyPass /tomcat/ http://localhost:8888/
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat/ http://localhost:8888/
```

You can read more about these directives [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).  Note that you may need to perform additional configuration of your Tomcat application to reflect the fact that it is externally visible at `/tomcat/`.

You can also potentially take advantage of virtual hosting, assuming that you control DNS for this system; in that case, you can have:

```
http://myserver-trac:8080/
```

Lead to a different `VirtualHost` configuration than:

```
http://myserver-tomcat:8080/
```

You can read more about name-based virtual hosting [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

Comment: Thank you! I think that the first way is simpler. Just a question: I can't find to which file I have to add those two line, can you help me?

Comment: They need to go somewhere in your Apache configuration.  I can't provide an exact answer because this differs from distribution to distribution, but possibly somewhere in `/etc/httpd/conf.d` or `/etc/apache2`.  Try searching for `apache configuration` + the name of your distribution (if you're using Linux) or operating system (for OS X or Windows).

Answer (score 0):

When you install the webservice listening on another port (at localhost), you can use Apache as a proxy (using mod_proxy) to access that service.

Maybe usefull: [How to rewrite / proxy an Apache URI to an application listening on a specific port / server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529324/how-to-rewrite-proxy-an-apache-uri-to-an-application-listening-on-a-specific-p)