# How to run Node.js app in Magento store?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, magento, express

I want to go www.mymagentostore.com/design and start running the node.js application. This application will produce a list of products, will add them to the cart and will redirect the user back to the store or to the checkout page.

I am not sure on how to implement this? Could you please advise, suggest or point to the example?

my thoughts:
1. Run www.mymagentostore.com on port 5000
2.once design button is clicked redirect user to www.mymagentostore.com/design on port 7777
3. Express framework on Node will listen on this port 7777 and route , will run the app , produce results, and will redirect back to www.mymagentostore.com on port 5000

Some questions arise if I think of implementation above:

Can I run php server on one port and node server on another one?
Can I run magento and node on the same domain name?
Will magento router cause problems for node router listener?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this via proxying in your webserver.

You can setup a directory alias in your webserver and have it proxy to the node.js app.

An example: [How to rewrite / proxy an Apache URI to an application listening on a specific port / server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529324/how-to-rewrite-proxy-an-apache-uri-to-an-application-listening-on-a-specific-p)

Comment: Thanks a lot I will research on this topic